# Plotting space regions and points

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, astropy

I'm trying to plot regions using astropy, but at the same time plot points as scatter plot. But I'm not managing to understand what is happening with the coordinates or the matplotlib artists.

First of all we can start defining the region,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import astropy.units as u
from gammapy.maps import RegionGeom
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, CircleSkyRegion

ra, dec = 60 * u.deg, 85 * u.deg

center = SkyCoord(ra=ra, dec=dec)
angle  = 1 * u.deg 
region = RegionGeom(CircleSkyRegion(center, angle))
```

Once we do that we can plot it using plot_region() attribute of region object, getting what we want. But if you also try to plot a point (the center of the region for this example) the coordinates have changed to what I think are pixel coordinates, and the point do not appear in our plot (that have coordinates around 0-1, not degrees nor radians).

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = region.plot_region()

ax.scatter(ra, dec)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Producing,

[image]

What can be the way to plot over this region with the scatter plot? I have the scatter points in degrees, I don't know how to convert it to the coordinates that are being used in the plot (most probably pixel coordinates).

Other thing I have tried is to define the axis before. Adding the projection that can be extracted from the region itself `region.wcs`, and then plotting over this axis. In this case the region is being plotted somewhere outside the part we can see. But now the scatter plot is working.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=region.wcs)
region.plot_region(ax=ax)

ax.scatter(ra, dec)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

What is the difference of the two axis definitions in the two approaches I have made? Shouldn't that produce same outcomes? I want to plot this regions (that are not circles, because are in fact distorted with the coordinate system) but also have some freedom to plot other things, because I can only do one thing or the other because of how this coordinate systems work with matplotlib.

Comment: Can you see `region.wcs` parameters ?  CRVAL should be close to the coordinates of the center of your region.
Also, cannot reproduce your example cause astropy has no CircleSkyRegion class 
(see : https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aastropy%2Fastropy%20CircleSkyRegion&type=code)

Answer (score 0):

You can add points to your plot with [PointSkyRegion](https://astropy-regions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/regions.PointSkyRegion.html#regions.PointSkyRegion). For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import astropy.units as u
from gammapy.maps import RegionGeom
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from regions import CircleSkyRegion, PointSkyRegion

ra, dec = 60 * u.deg, 85 * u.deg
center = SkyCoord(ra=ra, dec=dec)
angle = 1 * u.deg
region = RegionGeom(CircleSkyRegion(center, angle))

point = RegionGeom(PointSkyRegion(center=center))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = region.plot_region()
point.plot_region(
    ax=ax,
    facecolor="black",
    edgecolor="black",
    kwargs_point={
        "color": "black",
        "fillstyle": "full",
        "marker": "o",
        "markersize": 3,
    },
)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

which produces

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOWrz.png)